# long double division can not get the expected value

Tags: c++, printf, double, long-integer, division

I want to calculate the division between two `long double` numbers, but can not get the expected result. Anyone who can help me ?

```
int main() {

    long double m=(long double)(94911150.000000);
    long double n=(long double)(94911151.000000);
    long double k= m/n;
    printf("%Lf %Lf %Lf \n",m,n,k);
    return 0;
}
```

the expected result is    94911150.000000 94911151.000000 0.999999989

but the actual results is 94911150.000000 94911151.000000 1.000000

Answer (score 3):

The default precision of `%f` format specifier is 6. Try something like `%.10Lf`

Comment: Thx! What 's the precision of `%.10Lf`?

Answer (score 3):

An alternate solution since you tagged C++:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << k;
```

Note: Uses `#include <iomanip>`